# Excel Conditional Formatting based on another cells text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to get a cell to highlight green if another cell contains "True".
My expression so far is as follows:

```
If J4="True" 
  then highlight F4 green 
and 
  if J4="False" 
  then highlight F4 red.
```

It's not working.
How can I improve this formula?

Answer (score 1):

With Cell `F4` selected, add a new rule to your Conditional Formatting rules:

```
=$J4="True"
```

And apply a Green fill.  Use `=$J4="False"` and apply a Red fill for the negative side.

(Edit: For `True`, you can probably just do `=$J4`)

Comment: I was able to get it to work using =$J4 but using =$J4="False" did not work for the red fill.

Comment: @AndyGottschalk ah, just do `=$J4<>"True"`

Comment: @AndyGottschalk, what's actually in J4 (text words "True" or "False" or logical results)?  If it's text, `=$J4` shouldn't work, but everything in the answer except the edit should work.  The fact that `=$J4` works and `=$J4="False" doesn't suggests that you have logical results there.

Comment: @fixer1234 I have a massive if statement in J4 that will give me true or false depending on the number in F4 and one selected on another sheet. if that makes sense.

Comment: @AndyGottschalk, but is that true/false a logical value (TRUE, FALSE, 1, 0), or the text words "True" or "False"?  If it's a logical value, compare J4 to a logical value rather than to text (no quotes or 1 / 0 instead).

Comment: @fixer1234 it has the actual text "True" and "False"

Comment: @AndyGottschalk, is the formula in J4 giving you the results you expect?  If you have an error in the formula, it might be terminating and returning a logical value rather than the text you've specified.  An easy diagnostic: modify the formula in J4 so that instead of "True"/"False" it returns "Dog"/"Cat".  That way, there's no possible question on exactly what's being displayed (if you still see True/False it's a formula bug).  Also, verify that there are no invisible characters with the "True"/"False" in either location, like an extra space, because it performs an exact match. (cont'd)

Comment: If those steps don't identify a problem, it might help to add the formula from J4 to the question, along with values for any referenced cells.  This answer should work so if it isn't, we'll need to figure out what's going on in the spreadsheet.

Comment: @fixer1234 in the if statement I do not call for True or False to be displayed

Comment: @AndyGottschalk, then what are you comparing to in the conditional formatting?  What are the intended/actual results in J4?

Comment: @fixer1234 I figured out the problem, I needed to make J4 say True or False and it now works

Comment: @BruceWayne, this concludes the entertainment portion.

Comment: (@AndyGottschalk - Does this work for you, in the end? If so, you can flag it as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post.)